# Join data from two tables

Tags: sql-server, left-join

In my project, the customers of the company are calling to make requests about their equipment. Everytime a call is made, it's saved in database. Now I need to know how many calls did the company get every month of a specific year so I've written that request :

```
SELECT COUNT(EveLngId) FROM T_Evenement
where EveLngDosId = 1062
And EveLngBibId = 268
And EveTinSite = 1
And EveLngEleId <> 17432
And (EveTinParEmail is null OR EveTinParEmail = 0)
And (EveLngTicketTransfertId IS NULL OR EveLngTicketTransfertId = 0)
And (EveTinIncidentAnnulation is null or EveTinIncidentAnnulation=0)
And YEAR(EveDatRedaction) = 2013
group by MONTH(EveDatRedaction)
```

The request works but the thing is that when the value for a month is null, i doesn't display **Null** or **0** but it skips it. To manage that, I create a Calendar table as below:

[image]

So now I need to join these two tables to have the value for each month but I can figure out how to do that. Any advise or solution ?

Comment: So you want to join `T_Evenement` to your `Calendar` table? Can you give us some example data from `T_Evenement`?

Comment: @jyparask answered at my question, thank you for asking, will think to give more examples next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
;WITH ResultsCTE AS
(
    SELECT MONTH(EveDatRedaction) AS ResultMonth,
           COUNT(EveLngId) AS ResultCount 
    FROM   T_Evenement
    where  EveLngDosId = 1062
           And EveLngBibId = 268
           And EveTinSite = 1
           And EveLngEleId <> 17432
           And (EveTinParEmail is null OR EveTinParEmail = 0)
           And (EveLngTicketTransfertId IS NULL OR EveLngTicketTransfertId = 0)
           And (EveTinIncidentAnnulation is null or EveTinIncidentAnnulation=0)
           And YEAR(EveDatRedaction) = 2013
    GROUP BY MONTH(EveDatRedaction)
)
SELECT CalendarStrLibelle,ISNULL(ResultCount,0) AS ResultCount
FROM   Calendar 
       LEFT JOIN ResultsCTE 
          ON ResultMonth = CalendarLngId
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
SELECT  CalendarStrLibelle
    ,   ResultCount = ISNULL(cnt, 0) 
FROM dbo.Calendar c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
          [month] = MONTH(EveDatRedaction) 
        , cnt = COUNT(EveLngId) 
    FROM dbo.T_Evenement
    WHERE EveLngDosId = 1062
        AND EveLngBibId = 268
        AND EveTinSite = 1
        AND EveLngEleId <> 17432
        AND ISNULL(EveTinParEmail, 0) = 0
        AND ISNULL(EveLngTicketTransfertId, 0) = 0
        AND ISNULL(EveTinIncidentAnnulation, 0) = 0
        AND YEAR(EveDatRedaction) = 2013
    GROUP BY MONTH(EveDatRedaction)
) t ON t.[month] = c.CalendarLngId
```